# Kubuntu freezes after login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, suspend, freeze

In Kubuntu 14.04 I have installed the Recommended NVIDIA drivers with the driver manager and now the computer freezes a moment after login, if I access the terminal it doesn't freeze. The graphic card is G105M. I wanted to have the NVIDIA drivers for being able to suspend the computer.How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video card drivers version should be 340.46. I am sure you can open nviida-settings and check out version, and also adjust all related power-management fields in nvidia-settings.

In Kubuntu default power management, make sure you check your settings for all of the 3 sections present in there, namely AC POWER, ON BATTERY, ON LOW BATTERY. Disable **Dim Display** feature for AC POWER, ON BATTERY and ON LOW BATTERY, and disable **Suspend** feature for ON LOW BATTERY.

You can always reinstall your drivers from [nvidia official page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), and this is the link for [G105M 32bit](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/78468/en-us), and this one is for [G105M 64bit](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/78469/en-us). These are complete drivers, and not stripped drivers, and to install these drivers after downloading them you need to press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` key combination, login with username and password, and run the usual command for installing drivers. Nvidia installer will give you a prompt about uninstalling old drivers in order to install the new ones.

If you find errors when trying to install official drivers for nvidia cards, you need to install previously to that the following packages --> dkms fakeroot build-essential:

```
  sudo apt-get install dkms fakeroot build-essential
```

Aftyer that you reboot, and finally you can enter the text-mode console (press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` key combination, login with username and password) and install new drivers.

This one is for 32bit Ubuntu:

```
  sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-340.46.run
```

This one for 64bit Ubuntu:

```
  sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.46.run
```

After reboot, run this command in a terminal window:

```
  sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

And reboot again, and you're done, you can open nvidia settings with **sudo nvidia-settings** command, adjust settings to your preference, apply new settings and Save to x configuration file (uncheck "Merge with.." when saving your new X config)

Do the same steps in Kubuntu power management as shown above, and also make sure you adjust video drivers with nvidia-settings to match your power-manager configuration.

Comment: My drivers actualized and I had to do this again. Now I get: The client has the version 340.46, but this kernel module has the version 331.113. Please make sure that this kernel module and all Nvidia driver components have the same version.